# "Illegal value used for attribute name" during xslt transformation

Tags: exception, xslt, transformation

I am trying to transform an XML to another XML using an XSLT. Since the XSLT and the XML I am using is much bigger, I couldn't provide the data. While transforming, I could see the "Illegal value used for attribute name". In the result XML I could see some tags appearing twice. Below Ex:

```
<xslt:variable name="index" select="@Index">
<xslt:element name="EquipmentID-{$index}">
Hello
</xslt:element>
```

In the result, I am getting the result as,

```
<EquipmentID-EquipmentID-1>
Hello
</EquipmentID-Equipment-ID-1>
```

wherever I am using the $index, I am getting some awkward values.

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you post code, you should select the text and click the button that looks like `{ }` (or press CTRL+K on your keyboard) to make it formatted.  I've done it for you on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code and source data, it's impossible to help you with this. Your code is perfectly reasonable, and is perfectly capable of producing the output you have shown given suitable input (in particular the value of attribtute @Index)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but here's what happened in my case.

I was seeing this same error inexplicably (i.e., there was nothing wrong with the attribute name, and the error was occurring in random places), and its turns out it was due to performing XSL transformations simultaneously in different threads using Xalan version 2.7.0, which apparently has some bug in which it's not entirely thread safe when it is supposed to be.

I was using a common `Templates` but per-thread `Source`s, `Result`s, and `Transformer`s. This is supposed to be thread safe.

No idea exactly what the bug was, but in any case upgrading to Xalan 2.7.2 fixed the problem.